# How to deploy Django application developed locally in PyCharm to Web Server

Tags: python, django, pycharm, mamp

I made a project in Pycharm 2018.3 community version with Django and now I want to deploy to a web server to host the project. I'm using Mamp host the web server, but I don't know how to export/import my project from Pycharm to Mamp.

How do I deploy from Pycharm to the web server? What are the options for GitHub integration with Pycharm? Are there other ways to move the project to the web server while staying in the PyCharm IDE?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may fall under looking for opinions, but in general, PyCharm provides you with a few options. You can use the [deployments option](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/deploying-applications.html) by setting up a remote host (once you have your server set up) which allows you to develop locally, then sync up over ssh either automatically or when you goto Tools -> Deployment -> Sync Local to Deployed.

Although this previous option can work in PyCharm, I'd opt for and highly suggest setting up a git repository (Github, Bitbucket or other) then use PyCharm to commit and push your code to that remote repository. Then from your server, you can pull down the code from the git repository. This allows you the benefits of managing the code changes through all of the utilities a version control system provides.

You'll want to pay particular attention to any paths you have set in settings.py as they will likely differ on your server. One way to manage that is to use environment variables which allows you to refer to the environment variable, with your local development machine having it's own settings, and the server with its own set. https://12factor.net/config

Comment: Explained perfectly. I've got in mind the option you recommended but I wanted to be sure. Thanks very much!